# Searching by message-id in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to search by message-id in Outlook when it's connected to a generic IMAP server? Alternatively, is there a way to search for the message-id in the downloaded .pst file? I've done quite a bit of searching on this and I haven't found a way to do this with just Outlook and not Exchange.

Answer (score 8):

You have three options:

1. **Search in the selected folder only.** Customize current folder view or create a new one, click "Filter" and go to "SQL" tab in its settings. Set the "Edit these criteria directly" check and type the following:

   ```
   http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F = 'message-id-to-search'
   ```

   this will restrict message list to messages that have the "message-id-to-search" Message-ID.
2. **Advanced search.** You'll need to create a VBA macro for that. Good news it that it's only two functions long. In Outlook VBA editor (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), open Project1 -> Microsoft Outlook Objects -> ThisOutlookSession and create at least two Subs. Something like these ones:

   ```vb
   Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
       If SearchObject.Tag = "MessageId" Then
           Set Results = SearchObject.Results
           MsgBox "Message-ID search complete. " & Results.Count & " result(s) found."
           For i = 1 To Results.Count
               Results.Item(i).Display
           Next
       End If
   End Sub

   Public Sub SearchMessageId()
       Set Folder = Session.PickFolder
       If Not Folder Is Nothing Then
           r = MsgBox("Include subfolders?", vbYesNoCancel, "Search by Message-ID")
           If r <> vbCancel Then
               MessageId = InputBox("Message-ID:")
               If MessageId <> "" Then
                   Application.AdvancedSearch "'" & Folder.FolderPath & "'", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F = '" & MessageId & "'", r = vbYes, "MessageId"
               End If
           End If
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. **Use Outlook rules.** I mean "with specific words in the message header" rules. Disable them and run manually when needed to copy found messages or tag them with a flag and/or category. Do not forget to edit message-id to search for before each run!

Comment: I'm using Outlook 365 (v1807) and my SQL tab is in View > View Settings > Filter > SQL (check 'edit directly'). [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/3enwfVT). I do this step when I have the folder the message is in selected. However, it doesn't turn up any results. This would be my ideal method of the three, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe the message id on the screenshot is not exactly like this? Ofthen, you may see them in angle brackets  like <...> or something. Check Internet Headers of the message to ensure the correct value or try this SQL: `... LIKE '%...%'`

Comment: I confirm that the angle brackets are indeed needed.

Comment: this made my day :)

Comment: Thank you for the code!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to search for message-id in Outlook via Instant search or Advanced Find. All I can think of is using Outlook rules with the "With specific words in message header". Replace 'specific words' with the message-id you want to search for. Maybe outstand the email via copying/moving it to a specific folder.

[image]